# Custom Emoji Keyboard open behind Dialog in Lower API (API below 21) in android

Tags: android, keyboard

Custom dialog code is below in which i open custom keyboard on click of imageview:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity_Layout.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.edit_dialog);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.show();


ImageView emojiButtonDialog= (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.emojiButtonDialog);

emojiButtonDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(Activity_Layout.this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
            }
            else{
                showEmojiPopupDialog(!showingEmojiD);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            showEmojiPopupDialog(!showingEmojiD);
        }

    }
});
```

**Using this code Custom Emoji dialog works well in API>=21 but  In API<21 It's Open behind Dialog.**

Comment: Try to `dialog.dismiss()` when you called custom emoji dialog.

Comment: But in my custom dialog have an editText in which i want to type emojis